# Get all the values that start with a number in a data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, filter, dataframe

From a column (company_name) in a data frame df1, I want to get all the values which starts with a number. I am writing the code as -

```
df2 = df1[df1.company_name.str[0].isdigit()].copy()
```

I receive the following error -

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is digit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `str`, because [`str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html). Also I think `copy()` is not necessary:

```
df2 = df1[df1.company_name.str[0].str.isdigit()]
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['aa','1ss','wer']})
print (df1)
  company_name
0           aa
1          1ss
2          wer

df2 = df1[df1.company_name.str[0].str.isdigit()]
print (df2)
  company_name
1          1ss
```